# When sending file over to server, req.body is "{}"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file

I am trying to send a file to my express server to be saved.
On the front end, when I call `console.log(_("#fileElem2").files[0])`, I receive something like this:

[image]

Front End:

```
<input type="file" id="fileElem2">
```

```
_("#fileElem2").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log(_("#fileElem2").files[0])
    fetch('/uploadFile', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: _("#fileElem2").files[0]
    })
})

function _(query) {
    return document.querySelector(query);
}
```

Backend (server):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require('dotenv').config()
const http = require('http')
const port = process.env['port']
const path = require("path")
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
const helmet = require("helmet");

app.set('socketio', io);

app.post("/uploadFile", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
})

app.use(express.static('static'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(helmet())

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "html/index.html"));
})


server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on ${port}!`)
})

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // socketio stuff
})
```

When the `console.log(req.body);` runs, I only recieve `{}` in the console.
Am I supposed to be using `req.body` to recieve the file, or is there some other function?

Comment: `FormData` on the client-side and Multer on the server are really all you need

Comment: @Dai What is making it a JSON payload? I put `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}` into the fetch request, but now it is just logging `undefined`

Comment: @ghosty My mistake, I saw your remarks about only seeing `{}` so I jumped to an incorrect concusion from a faulty assumption - my earlier comment is now cheerfully withdrawn :)